# HTTPListener c# Web service issue when preform refresh

Tags: c#, sockets, httplistenerrequest

i want make web service by using HTTPlistener
and all is works as expected but the issue is when i do refresh or get out from website
and back
it not displays for me the web.

```
      int i = 0, k = 1;

    HttpListener server = new HttpListener(); 
    server.Prefixes.Add("http://10.0.0.7/");
    server.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server Running..");
    try
    {
        string path = "C:/Users/James/Documents/EndProject/webproj/";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        k = files.Length;
        while (true)
            {
            for (i=0; i < k; i++)
                {
                    HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
                    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Web URL: {0}", context.Request.Url.OriginalString);
                    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]);
                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    Stream st = response.OutputStream;
                    st.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHobw.jpg)

it happens just if i
trying approach again (F5,Refrash, or getting out and back again)
how can i resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: I think you are getting an exception and the server connection is not closing.  To check if connection is closing from cmd.exe use >Netstat -a   After exiting application the port number for your connection should close and not be seen in the Netstat results.  When you start the server you should see Netstat showing listening.  When client connects you should see the connect active.  And then when client close you should see nothing.

Comment: ok thanks and how should i resolve it in code?

Comment: I first wanted to know if my suspensions where really happening.  You should only send one response for every request received.  Your for loop looks real strange.  Not sure what you are trying to do.  You have a close  at end of the for loops so you close the response at end of first loop and then continue sending data.

Comment: OK i think you right when client get out from the web server i see in netstat -a still LISTENING

Comment: A listener can accept multiple clients so when client closes a connection the server is still listening.  Each active connection should be shown with client IP address.  Only one client  can be shown with the same IP.  If two applications from same client try to connect the second will fail.

Comment: in summery i want develop web service that will accept multiple clients
i have few file css,html,java-script that i want run into the web
what should i change in my code..
because i don't understand why it not working as i want/=..

Comment: Then use Async method so each client connection will create a separate callback event.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.start?view=netcore-3.1